# Excel - Trying to rank top 4 values in one column for each of the unique values in another column

Tags: excel-formula

I have excel spreadsheet containing some data and I am trying to figure out a way to do what is turning out to be a complicated evaluation on it.

For each unique value in column A, I would like to put values in a new column C, 1 through 4, for the   highest (up to) 4 values in column B.

I know the data is double sorted in the below picture, but if possible, would like to use a formula that doesn't rely on them being sorted.

For the  data below, for 202716-1, would like to see these, again not necessarily in the 1-4 order..

2548  1

2320  2

1906  3

1888  4

Then for 202716-2

1070   1

Then for 202751-1, would like to see

951  1

881  2

808  3

753  4

and so on..

I am having a really hard time figuring this one out, as it seems to require a filtering of values in one column, a "LARGE" evaluation on a 2nd column, and then some form of translation to a ranking 1 through a possible 4..

Any help would be appreciated, possibly i am over complicating it?

Thank You

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your feeling is pretty good. :) For a list of unique values paste [this](http://www.excelformeln.de/formeln.html?welcher=194)

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1,(COUNTIF(C$1:C1,A$1:A$99)=0)*(A$1:A$99<>""),0)),"")
```

in `C2` and pull downwards. For a list of the highest 4 values, if possible, enter

```
=IFERROR(LARGE(IF($A$2:$A$16=$C2,$B$2:$B$16),COLUMNS($D:D)),"")
```

in `D2`and pull downwards and sideways.

> ***Note*** Both are array-formulas which need to be confirmed through <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the  suggestion, i will take a look and try this out.. Thanks!